# Error while connecting to Spring Boot RSocket server from RSocket-Java Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-messaging, rsocket, rsocket-java

I am having issue while connecting to Spring Boot RSocket application over TCP. The client when using RSocketRequester works fine but when I try to connect using RSocketFactory client it keep getting errors. Code below.

```
        RSocket rSocket = this.client = RSocketFactory
            .connect()
            .mimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
            .transport(TcpClientTransport.create("localhost", 7000))
            .start()
            .block();


Flux<Payload> s = rSocket.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create("1234", "socket"));
    s.subscribe();
```

This gives error as below:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(1) + length(115) exceeds writerIndex(6): AbstractPooledDerivedByteBuf$PooledNonRetainedSlicedByteBuf(ridx: 1, widx: 6, cap: 6/6, unwrapped: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 27, widx: 27, cap: 1024))
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1477)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1463)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readSlice(AbstractByteBuf.java:880)
at io.rsocket.metadata.TaggingMetadata$1.next(TaggingMetadata.java:47)
at io.rsocket.metadata.TaggingMetadata$1.next(TaggingMetadata.java:37)
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.DefaultMetadataExtractor.extractEntry(DefaultMetadataExtractor.java:136)
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.DefaultMetadataExtractor.extract(DefaultMetadataExtractor.java:119)
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.MessagingRSocket.createHeaders(MessagingRSocket.java:195)
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.MessagingRSocket.handleAndReply(MessagingRSocket.java:167)
at org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.annotation.support.MessagingRSocket.requestStream(MessagingRSocket.java:127)
at io.rsocket.RSocketResponder.requestStream(RSocketResponder.java:207)
at io.rsocket.RSocketResponder.handleFrame(RSocketResponder.java:310)
at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drainRegular(FluxGroupBy.java:554)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:630)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.subscribe(FluxGroupBy.java:696)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8174)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:188)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1637)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:317)
at io.rsocket.internal.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.lambda$new$1(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:116)
at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drainLoop(FluxGroupBy.java:380)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:316)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onNext(FluxGroupBy.java:201)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:218)
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:351)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:348)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

This particular error is as I understand is because of netty message wrapping (from other threads on stackoverflow) but how to solve it? 
The server is Spring Boot 5+ RSocket but the client is only using RSocket-Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742430/rsocket-routing-metadata-using-rsocket-java-for-spring-rsocket-server/62776146?noredirect=1#comment111024666_62776146), use the following to generate metadata.

```
CompositeByteBuf metadata = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.compositeBuffer();
RoutingMetadata routingMetadata = TaggingMetadataCodec.createRoutingMetadata(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT, List.of("/route"));
CompositeMetadataCodec.encodeAndAddMetadata(metadata,
        ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
        WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING,
        routingMetadata.getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside mime types.
In your case server awaits `CBOR` but you proceed `application/json`

The code solution: change the way of RSocketRequester initialization as at the example below and you client with be sending `CBOR` you can see at by enabling debug: `logging.level.io.rsocket.FrameLogger: DEBUG`. That's all for hello world, no need custom strategies or factories implementations on the client-side

```java
@Bean
RSocketRequester rSocketRequester(RSocketStrategies strategies) {
    return RSocketRequester
            .builder()
            .rsocketStrategies(strategies)
            .connectTcp("127.0.0.1", 7000)
            .retry(5)
            .block();
    }
```

Btw, I didn't reach the solution with `JSON` on both side even with custom `Encoder` & `Decoder` on both side. I guess the reason here is that there is no `CBOR to Jackson` converter and only vice versa: `org.springframework.http.codec.cbor.Jackson2CborEncoder`

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am not using RSocketRequester on client side. The issue is when I put metadata (for routing, here "socket" is route @MessageMapping on server). Without metadata I get the payload on server fine. I am trying to figure out how Spring-Rsocket does the route mapping and send that in metadata.

Comment: As I understood: client send at the metadata `route: some` and rsocket server resolves it with `PathPatternRouteMatcher`

Comment: I think thats what I am trying to understand. What to put (encoding wise) int the route such that the default PathPatternRouteMater can route to correct endpoint (Server uses @MessageMapping from Spring).  If that is to complex, how to put custom RouteMatcher  that is both Spring friendly and works with rSocket. I have updated my code to make it understandable.