# rsocket routing metadata using RSocket-Java for Spring Rsocket Server

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket, spring-rsocket

How do I setup routing metadata (in payload using just RSocket-Java when server is using Spring Boot Rsocket.

`Flux<Payload> s = connection.flatMapMany(requester -> requester.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create("Some Message")))`

Server is using @MessageMapping("/route")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Interaction type

RSocket interaction type on SpringBoot using `@MessageMapping` is decided based on signature of annotated method (more info in [spring docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742430/rsocket-routing-metadata-using-rsocket-java-for-spring-rsocket-server))

Let's assume it is having signature:

```
@MessageMapping("/route")
Flux<String> getStreamOfStrings(String message) {...}
```

Based on cardinality table from spring docs interaction type is Request-Stream.

#### RSocket client

RSocket java client needs to have specified mime-type for metadata:

```
RSocket rsocketClient = RSocketConnector.create()
    //metadata header needs to be specified
    .metadataMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.getString())
    // value of spring.rsocket.server.port eg 7000
    .connect(TcpClientTransport.create(7000))
    .block();
```

#### Data

Data will be simple string:

```
ByteBuf data = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.buffer().writeBytes("request msg".getBytes());
```

#### Metadata

Routing in RSocket is defined as [metadata extension](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket/blob/master/Extensions/Routing.md) and needs to be sent together with data to specify routing. Here is example how it can be created (see other classes in package [io.rsocket.metadata](https://javadoc.io/static/io.rsocket/rsocket-core/1.0.1/io/rsocket/metadata/package-summary.html))

```
CompositeByteBuf metadata = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.compositeBuffer();
RoutingMetadata routingMetadata = TaggingMetadataCodec.createRoutingMetadata(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT, List.of("/route"));
CompositeMetadataCodec.encodeAndAddMetadata(metadata,
        ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
        WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING,
        routingMetadata.getContent());
```

#### Request-stream request

Data and metadata are created so you can execute `requestSteam` using:

```
rsocketClient.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create(data, metadata))
    .map(Payload::getDataUtf8)
    .toIterable()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This works!  Do we have to create metadata for each route or is here a way to use it from the List while creating Payload?

Comment: One option is to initialise metadata for each route and store it in Map(Route,Metadata) and use it when creating payload.