# Java RSocket client connect with Spring RSocket channel

Tags: java, spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java, spring-rsocket

I have simple Spring boot RSocket service

```
    @MessageMapping("msend")
    public Flux<String> msend(String message) {
        log.info("msend channel publish " + message);
        return Flux.just(message, " "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

It is easy to connect 2 Spring services, but my client application does not have spring, my client should be in RSocket java

I have difficulty to understand how to send (route, like Spring RsocketRequester) messages to that specific channel.

client code should be:

```
 Mono<RSocket> rsocket = RSocketConnector.create()               
            .metadataMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.getString())               
            .connect(TcpClientTransport.create(2050));


 ///real path "http://gateway:2022/producer/toProducerRsocket", 2050)
 ///toProducerRsocket redirect to producer/rsocket
```

Is it possible subscribe Spring channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks correct for defining the metadata type.  But you need to set it for the request stream. Channel doesn't sound correct here since you have a single input value message.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62776146/1542667

```
CompositeByteBuf metadata = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.compositeBuffer();
RoutingMetadata routingMetadata = TaggingMetadataCodec.createRoutingMetadata(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT, List.of("/route"));
CompositeMetadataCodec.encodeAndAddMetadata(metadata,
        ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
        WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING,
        routingMetadata.getContent());
```

Comment: If you search github, or the spring tutorials you should find a lot of examples of this.